# Mac OS X 10.6.8 - Can't remove SophosUpdate Packages/Folders on Desktop

Tags: macos, desktop

Every day a new "SophosUpdate" folder/package will appear on my desktop (see screenshot).

When I highlight it my trash can turns into an eject button.  When I drag them to the eject button nothing happens.  Also nothing happens when I right click one of them and select "eject".

The only thing that got rid of them once was starting up in safe mode but they keep coming back after that.

Does anyone know what I can do?  I'm stuck.

[image]

Comment: What version/edition of Sophos are you using?

Comment: It says Version 7.3.9

Answer (score 1):

> When I highlight it my trash can turns into an eject button.

This is a huge clue, because it indicates that this is a mounted volume (presumably a mounted image of the update package) and not an actual folder in `~/Desktop`.

If you enter `mount` or `diskutil list` at a terminal prompt, does anything called SophosUpdate show up? If you see one or more of these listed, you should be able to unmount it with `sudo diskutil unmount force /dev/diskN` where N is the disk number. Alternately, `sudo diskutil unmount force "/Volumes/Volume Name"` has the same effect.

Comment: Interesting idea, I just tried mount, and diskutil list but neither shows anything mentioning SophosUpdate.

Answer (score 0):

you have to do it through Terminal

```
# sudo rm -rf ~/Desktop/SophosUpdate
```

it should ask you for your password and return nothing, to verify that it completed without any errors try this command

```
# echo $?
```

if you get 0 that means everything went ok, if any other number then something was wrong. at that point I suggest you to try Disk Utility to "Verify Disk" and/or "Verify Disk Permissions"

Comment: Running that rm command doesn't do anything.  I do get 0 when I run the echo command.

Comment: make sure you do it with sudo in front and as I said if that still fails do step #2 and then try again step #1

Comment: If the trash icon is changing into an eject/unmount button when these are highlighted, they are not actually folders located on the Desktop and they cannot be removed with `rm`.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your Sophos antivirus cannot perform automatic update. Try running it manually or just disable auto updates.
Reinstalling it could also help.
Also, have you tried permission check from disk utility?

Comment: Any idea how I would disable autoupdate?

Comment: Should be in `Sophos Anti-Virus > Preferences`, then `Auto Update`; uncheck ` “Check for updates on connection to network or Internet”`

Comment: I don't seem to have Sohpos Anti-Virus in my System Preferences

Comment: Do you have the application installed?

Comment: Any recommendation to disable antivirus definition updates has potentially huge implications in terms of security, and in a litigious country like the USA one could even get sued for any negative consequences resulting from such a recommendation. Security is not meant to be taken lightly.

Comment: If you could get sued in the US for security malpractice on your home computer, at least 2/3 of home computer users would be on death row. Although this is the first time I've seen someone imply that disabling AV on a Mac could get you sued...

Comment: Ask me a question on ServerFault and I will assume that the context is a business environment. All of my current consulting clients are in the medical, financial, and manufacturing industries, so I think a lot about protecting health/financial information and trade secrets. Maybe @Greg_The_Ant is using this Mac to watch YouTube videos at home, but for all I know he's the IT guy at some small-town credit union.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up uninstalling sophos and installed the free personal edition instead of the one I had (corporate?).

It's been working fine since then.

I guess it still doesn't answer the more general question of how to remove a strange mounted item on your desktop with that red bar through it.  Any ideas on that?